# Doctrine ODM Query Builder - Find where collection is empty

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-odm

I am trying to create a query, using the doctrine ODM query builder, where a referenced association (`eventListeners`) **is not empty** - or the collection has one or more item.

The query:

```
$qb = $om->createQueryBuilder(FormService::ENTITY_CLASS_NAME_FORM);
$query = $qb->field('website.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($website->getId()))
            ->field('status.name')->equals(FormService::STATUS_PUBLISHED)
            ->field('eventListeners')->notEqual(array());
            ->getQuery();
$results = $query->execute();
```

I've been creative in my attempts with the API; This line is clearly incorrect as it still returns all the documents regardless

```
->field('eventListeners')->notEqual(array());
```

I can see in [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html) you can use `field('eventListeners')->size(3);` however I do not know in advance what the collection size should be.

**How do you query for non empty collections using Doctrine ODM?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not the best way to achieve this, but it does work:

```
$qb = $om->createQueryBuilder(FormService::ENTITY_CLASS_NAME_FORM);
$query = $qb->field('website.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($website->getId()))
            ->field('status.name')->equals(FormService::STATUS_PUBLISHED)
            ->field('eventListeners.0')->exists(true)
            ->getQuery();

$results = $query->execute();
```

This assumes that it is a 0 based index `Collection` and not a `Hash`.

I realise you can do `DB.find({eventListeners: {$not: {$size: 0}}})` in mongo, but I'm not sure how to properly structure it in the ODM query builder.

After reviewing the [odm documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html) I'm not sure if it's even possible to do.

The other approach is to use a `$where` function: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/